# Pandas groupby() mean questions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, statistics, mean

so I have a CSV file that has a [] of districts printed as columns that contain that contain rows of numerical data; I am wanting to derive a mean for each column iterated.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('ny_data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Upper Manhattan", "Inwood", "Harlem"])

df.groupby(["Upper Manhattan", "Inwood", "Harlem"])
resultdata = df.groupby([0])

resultdata =\
    ({df.groupby["Upper Manhattan"].mean(),
     df.groupby["Inwood"].mean(),
     df.groupby["Harlem"].mean(),
})

print(resultdata)
```

The csv file is random data generated by:

```
     nydata = pd.DataFrame({"Upper Manhattan" : np.random.randint(low=2000000, high=6000000, size=SIZE), "Inwood" : np.random.randint(low=3000000, high=3800000, size=SIZE), "Harlem" : np.random.randint(low=2300000, high=5000000, size=SIZE)}
```

I want a return output of each iterated column that provides a single mean per column. Another area I am not sure about after obtaining this output, using the same python file creating a new csv file with just the mean output from each iterated column.

The output comes out like:

```
Upper Manhattan    3.992766e+06
Inwood             3.397648e+06
Harlem             3.646264e+06
Leonx Hill         1.112454e+07
Astor Row          5.005024e+06
Upper East Side    2.357776e+07
dtype: float64
```

Thanks in advance and very sorry if this is all basic things - I am very new to programming but making *some* progress haha. I also have no idea what the 6e+07 etc mean?

Comment: Please provide a concrete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) (we don't know what's in your `ny_data.csv` file).

Comment: '''nydata = pd.DataFrame({"Upper Manhattan" : np.random.randint(low=2000000, high=6000000, size=SIZE),
                       "Inwood" : np.random.randint(low=3000000, high=3800000, size=SIZE),
                       "Harlem" : np.random.randint(low=2300000, high=5000000, size=SIZE)}'''  - so I used this to generate random data; this is what the csv file is based based on.

Comment: Can you pls edit the question with the example you provided in the comments? Also, mention what is expected output and what is the output you are getting. Without this, it would be not possible to provide any help

Comment: Yes, I've just done it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use groupby here. You may just want this:

`df.mean().to_csv("mean_values.csv", header=False)`

Regarding your other question, `e+07` means `multiply the value by 10 to the power of 7`, e.g. `3.992766e+06` = `3992766`.